# Oil Function On Leyden Jar Capacitor

Tags: capacitor

When i look into this tesla coil tutorial:
[www.instructables.com/id/How-to-build-a-Tesla-Coil](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-build-a-Tesla-Coil)

I that tutorial also explained how to make leyden jar capacitor.He said after pouring salt water into the bottle add a few ml of oil.What the function of that oil??Is that oil is to prevent any coat of iron oxide on the nail??

Comment: Not 100% sure but my guess is the oil just reduces the evaporation rate of the water.

Answer (score 3):

In a leyden jar (or rather, a salt water capacitor) the oil acts as an insulator, preventing corona discharge (and thus, wasted power) around the surface of the salt water. If you did not have it there, you would see tiny little sparks or a sort of blue "haze" around the outside "rim" of the water surface. This haze is called "corona" and is indicative of wasted power. In worst case scenarios, it can also weaken the container and cause it to melt or shatter. Oil helps reduce the chances of this happening.